# Dump memory in c use fwrite()

Tags: android, c, memory, java-native-interface, dump

I trying to make very simple dump memory program in `c` use `fwrite()` function but it occurred error...

This is my code, `dumpCode()` function get start address, end address, and name.

Then in for loop I want dump memory and make file.

```
void dumpCode( char* start, char* end, char* subject  )
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *i;
    char fileName[100];

    // make file name
    sprintf( fileName, "/storage/emulated/0/test/%s-%s.txt", start,end );

    fp = fopen( fileName, "wb" );

    for ( i = start; i <= end ; i++ )
        fwrite( start, 1,10*sizeof(unsigned long long),fp );

    fclose(fp);
}
```

I think it is very simple but I can't find error. What's the problem in my code ?

Comment: `I trying to make very simple dump memory program in c use fwrite() function but it occurred error...` But what is error? First read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm

Comment: Check if `fp` is `NULL` after `fopen`. This happens if the file cannot be opened/created for whatever reason.

Comment: Who says you can simply access any address? It is well possible that you can't and get an access violation/segfault. What is the error you talk about?

Comment: Your loop is pointless here, and certainly doesn't do what you think it does. Just use `fwrite(start, 1, end-start, fp);`. Assuming everything else is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you're trying to access to a file that does not exist. To be sure that you're not doing this mistake, you must check the return value of fopen. In fact, if the return value is NULL, it means that you're not trying access to a valid or existing file.

Here is what you should do :

```
void dumpCode( char* start, char* end, char* subject  )
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *i;
    char fileName[100];

    // make file name
    sprintf( fileName, "/storage/emulated/0/test/%s-%s.txt", start,end );

    if ((fp = fopen( fileName, "wb" )) == NULL)
        printf("Error: Could not open '%s'\n", fileName);

    for ( i = start; i <= end ; i++ )
        fwrite( start, 1,10*sizeof(unsigned long long),fp );

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `fp` is `NULL` or not after `fopen`.Only if the fopen ok,you can use `fwrite` to write data to file.Now,you don't know the error,you can print the `errno` to see what error hanppened.
Also,I notice,you `fopen` this file with `wb`,it means if this file exist,delete it and re-create it then write data.

```
#include<errno.h>
void dumpCode( char* start, char* end, char* subject  )
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *i;
    char fileName[100];
    int count = 0;
    // make file name
    sprintf( fileName, "/storage/emulated/0/test/%s-%s.txt", start,end );

    fp = fopen( fileName, "wb" );
    if(NULL == fp){
        printf("fopen error,errno is %d\n",errno);
    }else{
        for( i = start; i <= end ; i++ ){
            if(fwrite( start, 1,10*sizeof(unsigned long long),fp ) == 0)
                printf("fwrite error,errno is %d\n",errno);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```